# No-Tracking Objects in Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Well, In EF Core (NET CORE) we can make a query telling to framework not to track the object, but in JPA I don't know if this is possible.

I have the following query:

```
@Query("SELECT m.id FROM JpaEntity m WHERE m.payload.maquinaId = :maquinaId")
String buscarIdPorMaquinaId(Long maquinaId);
```

So, I get the ID to set in another entity that I'm updating, see:

```
 var id = repository.buscarPorCodigoMaquina("111");
            myEntityToUpdate.setId(id);
            repository.save(myEntityToUpdate);
```

But I got:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

I understand that JPA store entity in session (Persistent Context) but I need that JPA doesn't do it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure, what you are trying to do in the code given, but I thing what you are looking for is [`EntityManager.detach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach-java.lang.Object-). It removes the entity given as an argument from the 1st level cache, thereby making it a detached entity.

Comment: If you consider the tracking of entities a problem in general, you might be interested in Spring Data JDBC.